# Program using Qt, OpenCV runs fine when started from VS, but running the executable ordinarily crashes when OpenCV functionality would be used

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, deployment, release

I'm trying to deploy my C++ program. Every functionality of it works if I run the program from the VS IDE (release mode). When I ordinarily run the same executable, the main window comes up fine and its non-OpenCV functionality works; but when I try to open a picture and have the program use OpenCV stuff (opening it invokes the use of several OpenCV manipulations on the picture), it crashes.

I ran `windeployqt` from the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 successfully. It didn't copy the OpenCV dlls next to my executable, though, so I copied `opencv_world400.dll` and `opencv_ffmpeg400_64.dll` next to the other dlls. I assume this is the step where I'm missing something.
The folder looks like this now: 
[image: the executabe's folder]

I'm using VS2017 with Qt5.10.1 and OpenCV4.0. I don't think I can insert relevant code as the project is quite big and it uses OpenCV functionality extensively.

Comment: Have you tried running it through Dependency Walker to see if there's any missing DLLs?

Comment: Yes, but once I open it in Dependency Walker the app doesn't respond.

Comment: I use Opencv 3.4 with above configuration and had faced similar issue. The problem was, I had not copied  opencv .exes like opencv_version.exe , opencv_createsamples.exe. In short, try copying everything in the bin folder next to your qt application

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem was unrelated to OpenCV (`opencv_world400.dll` was sufficient to copy into the folder).

The problem was: I used Qt's `applicationDirPath()`, which returns the executable's path, to access a *Results* folder I was supposed to have previously created there, but did not. The program, if ran from VS, was accessing the existing *Results* folder in the *Debug* folder, even though I was running the program in release mode and `applicationDirPath()` was returning the executable's path in the *Release* folder. When I was running the same executable ordinarily, it couldn't find the *Results* folder and crashed.